# KendoNumericTextBox password type

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, kendonumerictextbox

Does anyone know how to get a Kendo Numeric TextBox to display asterisks as the user types them in?  `type="password"` does not work.  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="password" id="login_screen_password" data-bind="value: login_screen_password" />


    $('#login_screen_password').width(100).kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "#",
    min: 1111,
    max: 9999,
    spinners: false
});
$('#login_screen_password').attr('maxlength', '4');   // limit length of numbers inputted
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Kendo NumericTextBox for this ? You can achieve the same using normal textbox also, please see the [fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/vusupizelu/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<input type="password" id="login_screen_password" data-bind="value: login_screen_password" pattern="^[0-9]{1111,9999}$" />
```

Comment: thank you, but you cannot format the input as nicely without Kendo; I will submit a ticket to them and see what they say

Comment: telerik does not support the password type in their text box